# Is it possible to use VSCode Settings Editor UI with arbitrary settings json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Since Sep 6, 2018 VSCode has so called "VSCode Settings Editor UI" for visual editing of the

1. global VSCode settings
2. VSCode workspace settings
3. VSCode workspace folder settings

(https://twitter.com/ThePracticalDev/status/1037825020905631750)

**QUESTION**: is there a way to use "VSCode Settings Editor UI" in VSCode extension for editing of the settings file other than the listed above?

Example: some folder contains following json files (in proper format, which "VSCode Settings Editor UI" understands):

`some-settings-sun.json`

`some-settings-mon.json`

`some-settings-tue.json`

Is it possible to open one of these files in "VSCode Settings Editor UI", edit and save?